# Video Save with Texture View

Tags: android

i am trying to video effect using OEPNGL with android

i am downlaod source code project :
  https://www.virag.si/2014/03/playing-video-with-opengl-on-android/

apply video effect in this code.but how to store video in textureview in sdcard

play video :code

```
  private void startPlaying()
{
    renderer = new VideoTextureRenderer(this, surface.getSurfaceTexture(), surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight);
    player = new MediaPlayer();

try
    {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("big_buck_bunny.mp4");
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        player.setSurface(new Surface(renderer.getVideoTexture()));
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.prepare();
        renderer.setVideoSize(player.getVideoWidth(), player.getVideoHeight());
        player.start();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not open input video!");
    }

}
```

Apply effect code:

private static final String fragmentShaderCode =

```
"#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
"precision mediump float;" +
"varying highp vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +
"uniform samplerExternalOES texture;" +
"uniform sampler2D chrominanceTexture;" +
"void main () {" +
"mediump vec3 yuv;" +
"lowp vec3 rgb;" +
"yuv.x = texture2D(texture, v_TexCoordinate).r;" +
"yuv.yz = texture2D(chrominanceTexture, v_TexCoordinate).rg - vec2(0.7154, 0.0721);" +
"rgb = mat3(1,1,1,0,0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721,-.38059,0) * yuv;"+
"gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1);"+
```

"}";

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to some external library to save it as a video .
For example use ffmpeg.
check this link: [ffmpegDocumentation](https://ffmpeg.org/)
There is a clear documentation about it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30642635)